# Continued fraction : How to find the first 3 terms

Tags: continued-fractions

I can't calculate the exact first tree terms $F_0$, $F_1$ and $F_2$ of this continued
   fraction :

$$F_n=\cfrac{1}{-\text{i$\omega $}\,+A\,\cfrac{(n+1)^2}{{4
   (n+1)^2-1}}F_{n+1}}$$
 $A$ and $\omega$ are reals.

Please, how to obtain these terms ?

Comment: $$F(0) \text{ is in function } F(1)$$ and $$F(1) \text{ is in function } F(2)$$ then, if you replace, you heve $$F(0) \text{ is in function } F(2)$$

Comment: @Wmmoreno, yes i know, but how to obtain the general form of each terms without depending on other?

Comment: You can not do that. By the form in which the sequence is defined.

Comment: can you give me more details ?

Comment: If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, you always will have $F(n)$ depends of $F(n+1)$

Comment: so how I can do it?

Comment: Suppose we know the value of $F(0)$ and calculated on that value. Such that, if $F(0)\in \mathbb{C}$ fix ponit ..

Comment: Where did you get this, why do you want to know, and why do you not have an initial value?

Comment: Meanwhile, note that it is not difficult to solve for $F_{n+1}$ as a linear fractional transformation in $F_n,$ something of the form $$ \frac{B F_n + C}{D F_n + E}, $$ where your numbers $B,C,D,E$ will be complex numbers and depend on $n,A,\omega.$

Answer (score 0):

hint: calculate$F_{-1}$ first,then rest should be easy.

Comment: But n=0,1,2,...

Comment: do you have such limitation? if it is , then you can't get result.

Comment: so how I can do it ?

Comment: if $n\ge0$,you can only show $F(n）=f(F(n+1))$ or $ F(n+1)=g(F(n)) $, nothing else you can do. ie, you can do nothing.